# How to achieve multiple patterns with variable in grep?

Tags: grep

I have the following input file:
aaax
bbbx
cc
dd
aaay
ee
bbby

I want to write a grep command that will return the following. 
aaax
bbbx
aaay
bbby

Basically is there a way to achieve this in grep? I need a way to define a start and a stop pattern with matching suffix.

Comment: see https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Regular-Expressions

Answer (score 0):

Naive regex that matches your test case: `(aaa|bbb)(x|y)`.